# Where is "Film" setting to allow rendering transparent background?

Tags: rendering

I have been working with blender 2.79 and trying to render a two dimensional video with a transparent background. When I look up examples they all seem to use a tool called "film". I can't find this anywhere can someone help me. Am I missing a setting?

Comment: if I got what you mean, you have to use cycles render engine, then it's n the render properties

Answer (score 2):

You have to be in cycles render, then look to the render propreties tab

[image]